# Why NuGet Package manager Download/Copy Packages on multiple Locations?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package-restore

I have Directory Structure like -

```
Projects
   .nuget
      NuGet.exe
      NuGet.config
      NuGet.targets
      **packages (I want to download package for different solution HERE ONLY)**
   Sources
      Applications
         App1
            App1.sln (Solution File)
            **packages (NuGet downloads packages here first then copies to expected folder, WHY??)**
            App1 (Porject Directory)
               App1.csproj
         App2
            App2.sln (Solution File)
            **packages (NuGet downloads packages here first then copies to expected folder, WHY??)**
            App2 (Porject Directory)
               App2.csproj
```

I have referenced .nuget folder in each solution using following code

```
Project("{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}") = ".nuget", ".nuget", "{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx}"
    ProjectSection(SolutionItems) = preProject
        ..\..\..\.nuget\NuGet.Config = ..\..\..\.nuget\NuGet.Config
        ..\..\..\.nuget\NuGet.exe = ..\..\..\.nuget\NuGet.exe
        ..\..\..\.nuget\NuGet.targets = ..\..\..\.nuget\NuGet.targets
    EndProjectSection
EndProject
```

In every project file (.csproj), I have referenced common NuGet.targets using,

```
<Import Project="..\..\..\..\.nuget\NuGet.targets" Condition="Exists('..\..\..\..\.nuget\NuGet.targets')" />
```

In NuGet.config, I have added following line so that it should (must) copy packages in EXPECTED folder ONLY

```
<add key="repositoryPath" value="..\packages" />
```

I have mapped **Projects** folder with TFS and it asks me to add files on both locations because of above problem

Answer (score 0):

NuGet will look for the [NuGet.config file](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/nuget-config-file) based on the current solution's directory.

So taking your App1 solution if the Projects directory is in c:\Projects then your App1.sln file will be in the c:\Projects\Sources\Applications\App1 directory. Now NuGet will look for the NuGet.config directory in:

```
c:\Projects\Sources\Applications\App1\.nuget\NuGet.Config
c:\Projects\Sources\Applications\App1\NuGet.Config
c:\Projects\Sources\Applications\NuGet.Config
c:\Projects\Sources\NuGet.Config
c:\Projects\NuGet.Config
c:\NuGet.Config
```

After this it then looks in machine wide locations but I will ignore these for now.

Looking at your directory structure the Projects.nuget directory will not be checked by NuGet. It is not a parent of any of the solution directories.

I would look at putting a NuGet.Config file with the repositoryPath setting in the Sources directory or the Projects directory (not in the .nuget directory). Or having two NuGet.Config files, one in the App1.nuget directory and one in the App2.nuget directory.